# Linq to Excel, get column names from CSV file

Tags: excel, linq, linq-to-excel

I need to get the column headers of CSV files  with LINQ to Excel

I use the code specified on https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel

This works perefectly for .XLSX files but not for CSV

```
           //Select File

        var book = new LinqToExcel.ExcelQueryFactory(link + @"\" + fileName);

           //Select firtworkbook
        var query = (from row in book.Worksheet(0) select row).ToList();
        var workSheetName = book.GetWorksheetNames();
        var columnNames = (from row in book.GetColumnNames(workSheetName.FirstOrDefault()) select row).ToList();
```

I also tried hardcoding the sheet name and calling the CSV sheet1

```
        var columnNames = (from row in book.GetColumnNames("Sheet1") select row).ToList();
```

This breaks and gives me this error:

```
 Message = "'54733658.csv' is not a valid worksheet name in file...
```

I double checked it is the correct path.

I then tried:(It takes worksheet name which is the same as file name - extention)

```
        string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName);
        string result = fileName.Substring(0, fileName.Length - extension.Length);
        var colNames = book.GetColumnNames(result, "A1:F1").ToList();
```

This gives me the following error:

```
The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object '02119249$A1_Z1.txt'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.
```

I googled that error those results are not applicable.

Comment: Try to add the csv file to your project filesystem and access it with LinqToExcel.ExcelQueryFactory(fileName);

Comment: @abr I need the excel file to be uploaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have enough time to figure out why I cant read the CSV column headers

For those of you who have the same issue:

Read the first line and make a list of strings, here is my method:

```
    public List<string> ColumnNameGenerator(string FilePath)
    {

        string firstLine = "";
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FilePath))
        {
            firstLine = reader.ReadLine() ?? "";
        }

        return firstLine.Split(',').ToList();
    }
```